# DIV going down after using Inline Block

Tags: html, css

```css
    .dashboard-monthly-sales
        {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            background-color: #252525;
            border: 1px solid #595E57;
            width: 40%;
            height: 250px;
        }
    
        .dashboard-small-total-sales
        {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            background-color: #252525;
            border: 1px solid #595E57;
            width: 25%;
            height: 250px;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="dashboard-monthly-sales">
      <h2>Monthly Sales - <?php echo date("Y"); ?></h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dashboard-small-total-sales">
    
    </div>
```

This is my html code and css code when I add an element inside a div one block is going down. Is there any problem with display inline block part. I really can't figure out hope somebody will help

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I have used position absolute for h2 element and it works , any other solution for that?.And this won't help cause when the screen size is decreased the text position stays in the same position

Comment: From my understanding, inline-block works in the way you are wanting when used for list elements. ul li span etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `css` hope it's work

```
.dashboard-monthly-sales{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #252525;
    border: 1px solid #595E57;
    width: 40%;
    height: 250px;
    vertical-align:top; // Add this line in your code
}

.dashboard-small-total-sales{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #252525;
    border: 1px solid #595E57;
    width: 25%;
    height: 250px;
    vertical-align:top; // Add this line in your code
}
```

otherwise, you can use `display: flex` it helps you what you want

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding `vertical-align: top;` to the first div solves the problem. This tells the CSS to align the element to the top of the tallest element on the line.

```css
.dashboard-monthly-sales
        {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            background-color: #252525;
            border: 1px solid #595E57;
            width: 40%;
            height: 250px;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    
        .dashboard-small-total-sales
        {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            background-color: #252525;
            border: 1px solid #595E57;
            width: 25%;
            height: 250px;
        }
        h2 {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-monthly-sales">
      <h2>Monthly Sales - <?php echo date("Y"); ?></h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dashboard-small-total-sales">
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a main div containing the inner divs, so that all the inner divs will be aligned inside that main div. And use some css changes as below, so that adding the text inside the empty div will not affect the alignment.

```css
        .dashboard-monthly-sales
        {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            background-color: #252525;
            border: 1px solid #595E57;
            width: 40%;
            height: 250px;
        }
    
        .dashboard-small-total-sales
        {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            background-color: #252525;
            border: 1px solid #595E57;
            width: 25%;
            height: 250px;
        }
        .container{
        display: inline-flex;
        width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="dashboard-monthly-sales">
      <h2>Monthly Sales - <?php echo date("Y"); ?></h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dashboard-small-total-sales">
    
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the best way to go about it! I don't think you need to use `display: inline-block;` at all though.

Answer (score 0):

use one div as a container which will cover both divs. and in CSS use positioning properties and align it to according to your wish. first off all define the width of whole page.